# How to refer to test case name from soap request in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

I am looking for a way to use the current test case/test step name as a value in one of the attributes to my request xml.

Does anyone have the syntax? I looked up SoapUI docs, but couldn't find any

I am looking for something like

> ${#TestCase#TestStep#Label}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SOAPUI - SOAPRequest - Expand properties to access name property of current TestStep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358439/soapui-soaprequest-expand-properties-to-access-name-property-of-current-test)

Comment: Looks OP is looking for test case name as well. Realize late that OP required both case and step. So, adding the answer.

Comment: ObviousChild, have you got chance to look the solution provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TestCase Name

Here is how you can get the **test case name** in a `test request` step using property expansion:
`${=testCase.name}`

So, example can be

```
<testCaseName>${=testCase.name}</testCaseName>
```

If you want to use in `Groovy Script` step, then use
`log.info "test case name is : ${context.testCase.name}"`

## TestStep Name

In order to get the test step name, like albciff mentioned already, you can use the same `${=request.name}` in the `test request`.
*PS: credits to albciff, just adding here to make it complete.*

There is also another way to get the same is to use `${=context.currentStep.name}`.

So, examples can be :

```
<testStepName>${=context.currentStep.name}</testStepName>
```

or

```
<testStepName>${=request.name}</testStepName>
```

If the step type is `Groovy Script`, you can use

```
log.info "Current step name is : ${context.currentStep.name}"
```